# Extracting Dummy Variables from Rows of Values

Tags: r, dataframe, dummy-variable

I have a rather large set of delimited data listing characteristics of individuals in rows similar to these synthetic data:

```
id; ICD_Codes
1; F10.10; F11.21; F31.81
2; G89.29; M54.5; F31.4; F11.21; F17.200; F43.10; Z72.0
3; F14.10; F17.200; F31.81; F31.32; F10.21
```

(And yes, the number of "columns" varies for each row)

I would like to extract from it a series of dummy codes, one for each `ICD_Codes` value, and populate those dummy variables with whether a given individual presented with that value, i.e.:

| id | F10.10 | F10.21 | F11.21 | F14.10 | F17.200 | F31.32 | F31.4 | F31.81 | F43.10 | G89.29 | M54.5 | Z72.0 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 2 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 3 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |

Or, as an R dataframe:

```
df <- data.frame(id = c(1, 2, 3),
                 F10.10 = c(1, 0, 0),
                 F10.21 = c(0, 0, 1),
                 F11.21 = c(1, 1, 0),
                 F14.10 = c(0, 0, 1),
                 F17.200 = c(0, 1, 1),
                 F31.32 = c(0, 0, 1),
                 F31.4 = c(0, 1, 0),
                 F31.81 = c(1, 0, 1),
                 F43.10 = c(0, 1, 0),
                 G89.29 = c(0, 1, 0),
                 M54.5 = c(0, 1, 0),
                 Z72.0 = c(0, 1, 0)
                 )
```

I can think of no easy way to do this (anywhere, including in R), but surely there is way!

I would appreciate any help doing so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume you have not imported the data into R, we can use `read.table` to read the data as a single column (choosing a random `sep` symbol that you sure will not appear in your data).

Then split apart `id` and `ICD_Codes` into two columns, and use `fastDummies::dummy_cols()` to create the dummy variables. Finally `rename` to remove the column prefix to fit your desired output.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(fastDummies)

df <- read.table(text = "id; ICD_Codes
1; F10.10; F11.21; F31.81
2; G89.29; M54.5; F31.4; F11.21; F17.200; F43.10; Z72.0
3; F14.10; F17.200; F31.81; F31.32; F10.21", sep = "@", header = T)

df %>% 
  separate_wider_delim("id..ICD_Codes", names = c("id", "ICD_Codes"), delim = "; ", too_many = "merge") %>% 
  dummy_cols("ICD_Codes", remove_selected_columns = T, split = ";") %>% 
  rename_with(~sub("ICD_Codes_", "", .x))

# A tibble: 3 × 13
  id    F10.10 F11.21 F31.81 F14.10 F17.200 F31.32 F10.21 G89.29 M54.5 F31.4 F43.10 Z72.0
  <chr>  <int>  <int>  <int>  <int>   <int>  <int>  <int>  <int> <int> <int>  <int> <int>
1 1          1      1      1      0       0      0      0      0     0     0      0     0
2 2          0      1      0      0       1      0      0      1     1     1      1     1
3 3          0      0      1      1       1      1      1      0     0     0      0     0
```

Answer (score 2):

Without using additional packages you can use `readLines` and `strsplit`. Then do a cross-wise `grepl` using `outer`.

```
read <- readLines(textConnection('id; ICD_Codes
1; F10.10; F11.21; F31.81
2; G89.29; M54.5; F31.4; F11.21; F17.200; F43.10; Z72.0
3; F14.10; F17.200; F31.81; F31.32; F10.21'))

read <- lapply(read, \(x) el(strsplit(x, split=';\\s*')))
icd <- sort(unique(unlist(lapply(read[-1], \(x) x[-1]))))
o <- t(outer(icd, read[-1], Vectorize(\(sprintf('^%s$', x), y) any(grepl(x, y)))))
data.frame(id=sapply(read[-1], `[`, 1), `colnames<-`(+o, icd))
#   id F10.10 F10.21 F11.21 F14.10 F17.200 F31.32 F31.4 F31.81 F43.10 G89.29 M54.5 Z72.0
# 1  1      1      0      1      0       0      0     0      1      0      0     0     0
# 2  2      0      0      1      0       1      0     1      0      1      1     1     1
# 3  3      0      1      0      1       1      1     0      1      0      0     0     0
```

*Note:* For your real data you may want to use `readLines(<path>)`.

Evidence that it is much faster than the tidyverse solution:

```
# Unit: microseconds
#     expr       min         lq      mean    median        uq       max neval cld
#   jay.sf   965.285   994.9295  1264.239  1089.907  1124.969  16915.81   100  a 
# benson23 17309.835 17533.8145 20036.727 17822.965 18763.764 159236.18   100   b
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use `mtabulate`

```
library(qdapTools)
cbind(id = sub(";.*", "", df[[1]]),
   mtabulate(strsplit(sub("^\\d+;\\s+", "", df[[1]]), ";\\s*")))
```

-output

```
   id F10.10 F10.21 F11.21 F14.10 F17.200 F31.32 F31.4 F31.81 F43.10 G89.29 M54.5 Z72.0
1  1      1      0      1      0       0      0     0      1      0      0     0     0
2  2      0      0      1      0       1      0     1      0      1      1     1     1
3  3      0      1      0      1       1      1     0      1      0      0     0     0
```